# Need to remove special characters from string coming from database

Tags: php, regex, html, csv

I have products imported to the database from the csv file. And for product name, while storing the products, I am using `addslashes()` function. And on the front end, I am using `stripslashes()` function while displaying the product name.

But for some products, I am getting special characters while displaying, how I can remove those. I tried almost all Google results.
This is the link http://www.industrialstores.com/search_results/WD-40/46

While import, I am using query like this:

```
$insert_qry = "insert into  is_product_info set product_name = '".addslashes($data['product_name'])."',
                                                    sku = '".addslashes($data['sku'])."',
                                                    friendly_url = '".addslashes($friendly_url)."',
                                                    vendor = '".$data['vendorid']."',
                                                    manufacturer = '".$data['brandid']."',
                                                    retail_price = '".$data['price']."',
                                                    wholesale_price = '".$data['cost_price']."',
                                                    status = '".$data['available']."',
                                                    image = '".addslashes($image_name)."',
                                                    short_description = '".addslashes($data['teaser'])."',
                                                    tax = '".$data['product_taxable']."',
                                                    added_by='".$rs_employee_added['userId']."',
                                                    creation_date='".$today_date."',
                                                    added_by_name='".$rs_employee_added['firstname']. ' '. $rs_employee_added['lastname']."'";
```

And while displaying, like this `stripslashes($product_data['product_name']);`

Comment: Why don't you use PDO, active records or whatever provides readable and safe SQL statements? What you provided will be a maintanance nigtmare for you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use an [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to prevent them from running as code
Or you can RegEx them out.

```
$product_data['product_name'] = preg_replace('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+, '', $product_data['product_name']);
```

Comment: Whoops, missed a ' - code should be `$product_data['product_name'] = preg_replace('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '', $product_data['product_name']);`